# Submit form with JS do not perform basic validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why when I am using javascript the basic HTML inputs validation not performed?
Say the min max attributes.

Here the HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="get">Quantity (between 1 and 5):
    <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="with HTML">
</form>
<button id="sender">with JS</button>
```

JS:

```
$("#sender").click(function (event) {
    $("form").submit();
});
```

And live example: http://jsfiddle.net/txP4R/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to trigger the normal submit button:

```
$("#sender").click(function (event) {
    $('input[type="submit"]').trigger('click');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gopeter/txP4R/3/

Comment: In reality I don't have a real `<input type="submit"...`. I have only the JS button.

Comment: Than you have to add an invisible submit button :). There is a Javascript method (`checkValidity()`) to check the HTML5 validation, but it's not supported on all browsers, so you have to use this workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You need to associate the button with the form and check if the form is valid. See this 
jfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/txP4R/5/

The HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="get" id="form">Quantity (between 1 and 5):
    <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="with HTML">
</form>
<button id="sender" form="form">with JS</button>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$("#sender").click(function (event) {
    if (("#form")[0].checkValidity()) {
        $("#form").submit();
    }
});
```

Edit: Good catch A. Wolff

Comment: +1 `form` attribute is the way to go. Just one thing: `if (("#form").isValid())` Do you mean instead: `if($('form')[0].checkValidity() )` ?! Anyway, you shouldn't have to bind click event using form attribute. Now maybe OP should add `required` attribute for the `input`